# The limit for $x\to 0$ of $x^3\sin (x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

Give an epsilon-delta proof that the limit for $x\to 0$ of $x^3\sin(x)$ exists.

If I take a really big number for $x$ it doesn't seem to have a limit...

Comment: Compare `x-> 0` and `take a really big number for x`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to prove that : $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^{3} \sin(x) = 0$.

Note that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$,

$$ \vert x^{3} \sin(x) \vert \leq \vert x \vert^{3} $$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Take $\delta = \varepsilon^{\frac{1}{3}} > 0$. Then you have : $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, \big( \vert x \vert \leq \delta \big) \Rightarrow \big( \vert x^{3} \sin(x) \vert \leq \varepsilon \big)$

We just proved that :

> $$ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \; \exists \delta > 0, \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \; \big( \vert x \vert \leq \delta \big) \Rightarrow \big( \vert x^{3} \sin(x) \vert \leq \varepsilon \big) $$

Answer (score 1):

This expands Dids comment

It seems that you think taking a limit always has something to do with large numbers. This confusion probably comes from having seen a lot of limits being taken at infinity. When it holds that lim `x->infinity`  f(x) = c holds, indeed for every epsilon we can find a large number (X) so that for x>X we have |f(x)-c| < epsilon.

Often it is then reasonable to check if for a really big x number f(x) is close to c. (though really there can be examples where any large number you can think of is not large enough)

However, this limit is not taken at infinity, but at 0. If this limit b exists, it means that around 0 f(x) should be approximately b. So not for very large numbers x.